# Read content from files once ... Static or Singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

Using ASP.NET Core 3.0 I have a PostService which reads the content of a few Markdown files:

```
public class PostService : IPostService {

  private String _basePath;

  public PostService(IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment) {
    _basePath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;      
  }

  public async Task<IList<Post>> GetAllAsync() {

    IList<Post> _posts = new List<Post>();

    String[] files = Directory.GetFiles($"{_basePath}/posts", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (String file in files) {

      String content = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(file);

      // Process content and create 'post' from content 

      _posts.Add(post);

    }

    return _posts;

  }

}
```

And I use it as follows on a controller:

```
public class PostController : ControllerBase {   

    public PostController(IPostService postService) {
      _postService = postService;      
    }

    [HttpGet("posts/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Int32 id) {

      Post post = _postService.GetAllAsync().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

      // Remaining code
    } 
}
```

I do not want to load the files in every request as they do not change.

Should I add PostService as Singleton?

```
services.AddSingleton<IPostService, PostService>();
```

Should I store posts in a Static variable inside PostService?

What would be the best way to avoid loading and reading the files all the time?

**Update**

Using a static field in PostService would be something like:

```
public class PostService : IPostService {

  private static List<Post>() _posts;

  private String _basePath;

  public PostService(IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment) {
    _basePath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;      
  }

  public async Task<IList<Post>> GetAllAsync() {

    // Check if Posts were already loaded.
    if (_posts != null)
      return _posts; // If yes then return _posts and do not load files

    String[] files = Directory.GetFiles($"{_basePath}/posts", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (String file in files) {

      String content = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(file);

      // Process content and create 'post' from content 

      _posts.Add(post);

    }

    return _posts;

  }

}
```

Is this the way to go? Should I load the posts in constructor?

Comment: What's the purpose of having this as a service? Testing?

Comment: Yes, for testing ... And also to have a class responsible for the loading and parsing the files which will be used in a few controllers.

Comment: Is there a chance of `GetAllAsync()` being called concurrently? If so, the static variable solution could run into issues with the variable being loaded more than once if/when multiple equests get into the method while the variable is still null

Comment: Have you considered putting it in [cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.0)?

Comment: @devNull Yes, being in a web application that could happen.

Comment: @JohnWu You mean, adding the List of posts in cache after loading from files? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the class to be a singleton, you are condemning it to forever be that - a singleton.  The class (I am assuming) will be doing more than just store posts.  You may find that you need it to be something other than a singleton.

I'd store the list as a static variable.

There are also other methods to hold cached items in memory that are optimized for that purpose (e.g. System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache).

Comment: I just updated my question with an update. Should I load the posts in a static constructor? Or something as I suggest in the Update?

Comment: When the class starts doing more than just caching posts, a new service can be added. I don't buy the condemnation argument :)

Comment: One of the reasons why I would like to do this in the class is just if by mistake in the future someone sets the Service as Transient then there will be not problem with that as the class would "cache" the posts ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura Responding to the changes in the question and some comments.  If you have to inject something (e.g. IWebHostEnvironment), then obviously it will be difficult to get the information from a static constructor.  Have you thought of getting this information separately from the class (say on the startup on the application), and then accessing it from the class?

Comment: @AngryHacker I would prefer to inject it as I will need to write some tests.

Comment: @MiguelMoura In that case, I'd store the data separately, perhaps in a static class that gets populated on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I think both options are OK.

---

> Using a static field in PostService

Static constructor will be thread safe out of the box. A lazy loaded member needs to be made thread safe.

Comment: One problem I am getting with static constructor is that I need to inject in the service an instance to get a BasePath.

Comment: That sounds like it's a no for the static constructor then.